# adjective word or any expression used to describe a child's behaviour

Tags: adjectives

Please could you help me with an adjective word or any expression used by English Native Speakers to describe a child who habitually likes to always lean or rub his or her body against the body of another person especially their parents or other adults like cats do against the body of their carers or owners. I used to describe them as clingy child, sticky child or adherent child but I felt like none sounded or communicate well to me.

Comment: The way you describe them, *clingy*, hits the mark. It's what I would use.

Comment: Please let us know what the word would be in your native language.

Comment: @James K. We say "Kwalafuci" or "son-jiki".

Comment: @James K. As for the word "clingy" it is equivalent in my native Hausa language is "dafa". Where as the two words in my language that is " Kwalafuci" or "son-jiki" and "dafa" are two different words used in different situations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In this context, *clingy* is different I feel.

> [clingy](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/clingy): *A clingy person stays close to and depends on a person who is taking care of them.*

The example follows:

> *Jimmy is a very clingy child.*

So, if you refer a kid or a person as *clingy,* you are saying that the person is pretty dependent. I'm afraid, this ***does not talk*** about the physical habit you have mentioned.

In such cases where we have **no single word**, I feel using *a group of words.* And, you already know this!

> A kid with *cat-like behavior. S/he rubs her/his body with parents or people nearby.*

---

Or **for fun,** if Batman has bat-like behavior, a *catkid* may have cat-like behavior! :P

Comment: @ Maulik V. Thank you. Your argument is so helpful, it exactly hit my itchy spot. I like the expressions you suggested "cat-like behavior" or    "catkid". Somebody suggested another word "touchy-feely" ie."touchy-feely kid" to express  such situation. Please is your opinion on the later expression.

Comment: I'd still stick to 'cat-like' because I haven't heard 'touchy feely' before. Also, even if you use it, you may need to explain what that word means. Cat-like will pass on the hint of 'cat-like' behavior in some or the other way.

Comment: Thank you for taking me through your time with such valuable information. It is so noted.